# Split list of datetime objects into keys(date) and values(times)

Tags: python, sql, datetime

I have a column of datetime objects under CREATEDDATE in the Calls table.

```
2013-08-09 12:19:09
2012-06-10 09:08:10
2009-08-11 10:15:00
2013-08-09 11:20:09
2013-08-09 06:12:04
2013-08-09 01:09:15
```

I want to create a dict using the dates as the keys and the times as the values.

I originally wanted to run

```
select (CAST CREATEDDATE as DATE) from Calls where Town = 'New York'
```

and then go through each of the dates to bring up the times from each date

```
select(CAST CREATEDDATE as TIME) from Calls where CREATEDDATE = '8/11/2009'
```

and input the values into a dict, but the above query does not work.

I'm looking for either a simple way for me to convert a list of datetime objects into a dict or a way to select the times from the datetime object column based on its date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read datetime as str and use following code to create dict:

```
dt = ['2013-08-09 12:19:09','2012-06-10 09:08:10','2009-08-11 10:15:00']
adict={}
adict.update(ddtt.split() for ddtt in dt)
print adict
```

Output:

```
{'2009-08-11': '10:15:00', '2012-06-10': '09:08:10', '2013-08-09': '12:19:09'}
```

EDIT:

If you have same date associated with multiple times, you can create dictionary keys with value pointing to list. For ex, if your data (repeated  2013-08-09 for different time)

```
dt = ['2013-08-09 12:19:09','2012-06-10 09:08:10','2009-08-11 10:15:00', '2013-08-09 12:19:10']
```

You can get the output:

```
{'2009-08-11': ['10:15:00'], '2012-06-10': ['09:08:10'], '2013-08-09': ['12:19:09', '12:19:10']}
```

Following is the code for getting this:

```
adict={}
for ddtt in dt:
    data=ddtt.split()
    if data[0] in adict:
        adict[data[0]].append(data[1])
    else:
        adict[data[0]] = [data[1]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are multiple times associated with a day, around 1700 different times per date.  I'll edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: you can have list instead of one value in dictionary